# How can I move the centos user's homedir using ansible?

Tags: ansible, centos

I've got a CentOS cluster where `/home` is going to get mounted over nfs. So I think the `centos` user's home should get moved to somewhere which will remain local, maybe `/var/lib/centos` or something. But given `centos` is the `ansible_user` I can't use:

```yaml
hosts: cluster
become: yes
tasks:
  - ansible.builtin.user:
      name: centos
      move_home: yes
      home: "/var/lib/centos"
```

as unsurprisingly it fails with

```sh
usermod: user centos is currently used by process 45028
```

Any semi-tidy workarounds for this, or better ideas?

Comment: I don't think that's valid - become can be "yes" (which is what I was running with, I should say that), you can set "become_user" but the default is "root". I think the problem is that it's just running `sudo` so you're still logging in a centos.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this with the `user` module if you're connecting as the `centos` user. However, if you handle the individual steps yourself it should work:

```
---
- hosts: centos
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - command: rsync -a /home/centos/ /var/lib/centos/
    - command: sed -i 's,/home/centos,/var/lib/centos,' /etc/passwd
      args:
        warn: false
    - meta: reset_connection
    - command: rm -rf /home/centos
      args:
        warn: false
```

This relocates the home directory, updates `/etc/passwd`, and then removes the old home directory. The `reset_connection` is in there to force a new ssh connection: without that, Ansible will be unhappy when you remove the home directory.

In practice, you'd want to add some logic to the above playbook to make it idempotent.